# ToggleButton Binding ViewModel

Tags: binding, viewmodel, togglebutton

Hi I would like to binding a Togglebutton with the ViewModel . Below is the view code

```
 <ToggleButton Content="Toggle" Width="80">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=CheckedCommand}"/>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=UncheckedCommand}"/>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </ToggleButton>
```

Could anyone help me with the corresponding ViewModel Code ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Prism? If not, you'll also need to implement DelegateCommand in either this or BaseViewModel class.

```
    public class YourViewModel
    {
        private DelegateCommand _checkedCommand;
        public DelegateCommand CheckedCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _checkedCommand ?? (_checkedCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnCheckedCommand));
            }
        }

        private DelegateCommand _uncheckedCommand;
        public DelegateCommand UncheckedCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _uncheckedCommand ?? (_uncheckedCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnUncheckedCommand));
            }
        }

        private void OnUncheckedCommand() { }

        private void OnCheckedCommand() { }
    }
```